# Full-stack React app deployed on Cyclic.sh throwing 404 on page refresh when not on root route

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, hosting

I have my front and back-end code hosted on Cyclic.sh and the site works perfectly except when a page is refreshed and I am not on the homepage. Refreshing here "website-name.cyclic.app/" works but not "website-name.cyclic.app/any-other-route". **I believe this is due to React's client-side routing and my back-end being unable to enter from the index.html file on page refresh.**

I have a dist folder in my front-end that holds my production code and in my server.js file in my back-end code I have added this, as per Cyclic's documentation on deploying static sites:

```
var options = {
  dotfiles: 'ignore',
  etag: false,
  extensions: ['htm', 'html', 'css', 'js', 'ico', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'svg'],
  index: ['index.html'],
  maxAge: '1m',
  redirect: false,
};

// Serve static files from the 'dist' directory.
app.use(express.static('dist', options));
```

But this is not fixing the issue. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Here's what I did to solve this as per Benard's suggestion, plus re-arranging my file structure:

1. Move my front and back end into a monorepo, where my front end is in a 'client' folder.
2. Add this to my server.js file (make sure to import path)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/dist/index.html'));
});
```

The biggest issue was that I wasn't fully understanding what was happening between my front/back end. Now that they are in the same repo, my server is able to serve up the static files from the build folder and everything works correctly.

Comment: You have to serve all your routes in express with something like `app.get('*', (req,res) => {
// send yourIndex.html here
})`

Comment: Do I need to alter all of my routes? Or is it sufficient to put something like you have above in my server.js file?

Comment: Just below all your routes, the last one...

Comment: I have updated my post with what I have now. I'm still not having any luck with this code

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with

```
const fs = require('fs')

// your other code

app.use(express.static('dist'));

// All your other routes here

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  const content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'), 'utf-8')

  res.send(content);
});

connectDB().then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out with the guidelines you provided above, I edited my initial post. Thank you so much for your help!